# Spring Integration Poller not working in Pivotal Cloud Foundry without application restart

Tags: spring-integration, pcf, poller

I have a spring integration poller, that polls a directory in NAS. The poller picks up files perfectly fine when running the application in local. But in PCF, it picks up the file only during application startup or when the app is restarted. I have enabled debug logging for Spring Integration and have verified that the poller is running at the scheduled interval in PCF. But it doesn't pick up the files. The NAS share is bound to the app by SMB Volume Service.Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue the same day. I was using WatchService which is not expected to work on a mount path in PCF (inotify on linux system). So I updated my poller to use RecursiveDirectoryScanner instead of the WatchServiceDirectoryScanner that is used when UseWatchService is set to true in the poller config.